# Failover boot image

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grub, u-boot

I am trying to create a failover boot image for Ubuntu. The images will be on an SDCard System, and my intent is that if one boot image fails, the other will load.

I am using UBoot and Ubuntu.

Additionally I would like to repair the broken partition from the other ... How does one do this? Is it also possible to have a failover for the boot loader?

```
Model: SD SR400 (sd/mmc)
Disk /dev/mmcblk0: 394GB
Sector size (logical/physical): 512B/512B
Partition Table: msdos
Disk Flags: 

Number  Start   End     Size    Type     File system  Flags
 1      4194kB  128MB   124MB   primary  fat16        lba
 2      128MB   3670MB  3542MB  primary  ext4
```

Comment: @Fabby I have added the parted --list

Comment: So can I have a second boot image on an SD Card?

Comment: I am interested in a fallback ~ http://www.linuxscrew.com/2012/04/24/grub-fallback-boot-good-kernel-if-new-one-crashes/ ... Something like this, but for Uboot

Comment: Ah.  Comments deleted.  I know nothing about UBoot...